# Access Denied when using Copy to LPT port

Tags: windows-8, permissions, printing

I print some data to a connected printed via the dos COPY command.

It works great when the printer is set to "spool" but when using "print directly to printer" windows returns an access denied error.

The user is an administrator. I have tried adjusting the Win32/Spool directory to allow full RW permissions.

I've had the issue under Windows 7 and Windows 8.

The printer is connected via USB and is shared using NET USE as LPT3 via local ip, ex:
net use lpt3 \127.0.0.1\printer /persistent:yes

When using the spooler and printing large sets of print jobs it seems like the spooler is getting maxed out (I can't find a limit to # of jobs) thus the desire to print directly.

Comment: do you have the same problem if you don't  pass through a LPT3 mapping? e.g. just `copy filename \\127.0.0.1\printer`?

Comment: Is this on the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

When you print to spool, you are converting the file you want to print into the spool directory on the local hard drive and the operating system is pushing it out to the printer.  When you print to LPT3 127.0.0.1\printer you are going out the network stack and back into the computer as if you are a remote computer.  This method introdues SNMP, firewalls, shared print permission issues and other assorted issues.  "Access denied" is a very specific error suggesting that you have made it through the firewall but either outward facing shared ACL or the internal ACL does not allow you to do what you are doing.  Does this "access denied" occur when you print to LPT3 or USB or both?

Comment: "access denied" only occurs when the spooler option is set to print direct, not when set to spooling. the printer is always connected via USB, but shared and captured as LPT3.